# Ldapsearch and range limit

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a problem with the `ldapsearch` command.

I want, with ldapsearch binary, to list a limited number of member from a LDAP group. For example, I want to only get members 1 to 50 of a request.

`ldapsearch -x -h <ldap_serv_addr> -p <ldap_port> -b "<base-dn>" "(&(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user))(memberOf=<group_dn>))"`

This request gives me (and it works fine) **all** members of group . I only want a "range" of them.

I know I have to use something like `member;range=1-50`, but I don't know where to put this in the ldapsearch command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using member with a range is a solution when you are returning a multi-value attribute for an object, not a set of objects. In this example, I am searching for a specific group and returning groups of 50 members (correct objectClass for your groups can vary, check out an object. Or, if it's a unique name, just omit objectClass from the filter):

```
ldapsearch -x -h <ldap_serv_addr> -p <ldap_port> -b "<base-dn>" "(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=<groupCN>))" "member;range=0-50"
```

In your example query, you are asking to identify objects that have memberOf set to the groupDN -- this isn't a single multi-value attribute on an object but rather a set of objects. You control the size of the set up objects using paging. *How* you request paged results depends on the client/language (and some LDAP servers do not support paged operations). Using ldapsearch, and assuming the LDAP server supports paged queries, your command line would be:

```
ldapsearch -x -h <ldap_serv_addr> -p <ldap_port> -E pr50/prompt -b "<base-dn>" "(&(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user))(memberOf=<group_dn>))"
```

-E pr50/prompt sets the page size to 50 and prompts to continue to the next page.

I don't know of any way to non-interactively stop after the first page of results, and it is more straightforward to search for a group and return its member list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations, I understard the difference now.
It solved my problem using pagination like you said !